# Angular : Close div after click outside parent div

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I know how to close a div after click outside the parent div with jQuery . something like this :

```
$(document).on("click", function (e) {
        if (e.target.id != "user-login-top" && !$(e.target).closest("#user-login-wrapper").length) {
            $("#user-login-wrapper").removeClass("wide");
        }
    });
```

how can i convert this to a directive to use it globally , like backdrop in `modal` (angular.ui) . 
here is the [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/zqdmny41/22/)

i want to close menu with any click outside the parent div .
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please specify a proper example. Your example didn't match with fiddle. Where you want to click to close what?

Comment: yeah i just want to give you a hint

Comment: the fiddle shows you a button(top left), when you click this button, it open the menu(right side) , i want to close menu after click outside the menu .

Answer (score 0):

Do you already tried  `angular.element(document).on('click', function (event) {});`?

Comment: What is restrict 'C'?

Comment: did you talk about directive ??

Comment: I used the construct in a directive, but angular is also available in the controller.